# Как называется эффект?

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Хочу для портфолио, на карточках со своими сайтами сделать эффект, когда наводишь на карточку то сайт внутри карточки начинает скролиться вниз, подскажите как это загуглить, как этот эффект называется, или может если знаете библиотеку для этого то название дать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно установить скриншонт сайта как фон блока и менять background-position при наведении мыши (:hover). Чтобы изменение было плавным, используйте [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov вы имеете в виду сделать длинный скриншот всего сайта и просто двигать вниз при наведении?

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov сделал по вашему совету, мне подходит, могли бы сделать ответ я отмечу как верный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно установить скриншонт сайта как фон блока и менять background-position при наведении мыши (:hover). Чтобы изменение было плавным, используйте transition –
Alexey Vladimirov

Данный комментарий мне помог и я добился нужного результата.